# why can't i get the agent from behaviour instance?

Tags: java, aspectj, agents-jade

i am working with JADE in Eclipse. i tried to capture the *action* method for each executed behaviour using an aspect. it works so well, i even got the instance of the executed behaviour. however this instance doesn't allow me to get the Agent which added this behaviour. because in http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/core/behaviours/Behaviour.html Behaviour allows us to know which Agent added this behaviour. the following pic shows my error

[image]

thanks.

Comment: No, the pic does *not* show the error, just the place in the code where it seems to occur. Would you mind updating the question by actually quoting the exact error message? Probably it already explains what the compiler complains about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for *not* updating the question, not posting the actual error message and even hiding your class's imports from your readers' view. `:-7`

Anyway: The code you posted should work, for me it does in Eclipse without any red underlinings. Here are two variants for your pointcut and advice, on like yours with an ugly cast and usage of `getThis()` and one more elegant by direct and type-safe parameter binding:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import jade.core.behaviours.Behaviour;

public aspect ActionAspect {
    before() :
        execution(* Behaviour.action(..))
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        Behaviour behaviour = (Behaviour) thisJoinPoint.getThis();
        behaviour.getAgent();
    }

    before(Behaviour behaviour) :
        execution(* Behaviour.action(..)) && this(behaviour)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        behaviour.getAgent();
    }
}
```

Comment: but still, even with your code, i am getting red underlinings
what is your jade version please ?! 
i have an assumption that the version is the source of my problem

Comment: *You* are asking *me* for details and you are too lazy to provide any?! Come on! After you, Sir. I am waiting.

Comment: yes i was right
i found the problem , the jade v4.3.3 is offering getAgent() in the Behaviour calss
thanks so much sir
but now i am facing another problem
i will edit the question

Comment: So you opened a question here because you tried to call a non-existent method. Okay, no further comments on that. I kindly suggest to accept my answer and not to edit the question (you have not done so in 4 hours now anyway) because the follow-up problem would probably unrelated.